# Is Oracle killing Opensource Netbeans in favor of JDeveloper?

Tags: netbeans, uml

To my surprise Netbeans UML plugin is no longer supported. Jdeveloper UML features is not equivalent to this plugin so my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what **[Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/documents/webcontent/038563.pdf)** says, as of January 27, 2010

> **What are Oracle’s plans for NetBeans?**
>
> Oracle has a strong track record of demonstrating commitment to choice for Java developers. As such, NetBeans is expected to provide an additional open source option and complement to the two free tools Oracle already offers for enterprise Java development: Oracle JDeveloper and Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse. While Oracle JDeveloper remains Oracle’s strategic development tool for the broad portfolio of Oracle Fusion Middleware products and for Oracle’s next generation of enterprise applications, developers will be able to use whichever free tool they are most comfortable with for pure Java and Java EE development: JDeveloper, Enterprise Pack for Eclipse, or NetBeans.

Now, you can read between the lines if you wish, and assume that the support for NetBeans will be for "pure Java and Java EE development" only, which might not include UML tools.

I guess we will see.

Comment: My reading between the lines of this Oracle Mumbo Jumbo is that they will favor their development tools or commercial plugins instead of Opensource Netbeans :) Sad. Netbeans had unique UML Sequence Diagram REVERSE ENGINIERING Tool, on Eclipse it's a Plugin that is sold 10000 $ :( On Visual Studio the same thing, it's only on Ultimate Edition.